# Worpitzky numbers as coefficients in summation formulae

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

The following exercise problem appears in Rozanov's *Probability Theory: A Concise Course*:

> Balls are drawn from an urn containing $w$ white balls and $b$ black
>   balls until a white ball appears. Find the mean value $m$ and variance
>   $\sigma^2$ of the number of black balls drawn, assuming that each ball
>   is replaced after being drawn.

One way of solving the problem requires one to 
consider a function $S(k)$, and
find its values for $k=1$ and $k=2$
(to compute the mean and variance, respectively):

$$S(k)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty i\,^kar^{i-1}$$

Assume for convenience that $\left|\,r\,\right|<1$.
When $k=0$, this is
a geometric series, so $S(0)=\frac{a}{1-r}$.
Values of $S(k)$ for higher $k$ can be worked
out by hand. For $k=1,2,3,4$, I get the following.

$$
\begin{array}{lll}
S(1)&\quad=\quad&\frac{a}{\left(1-r\right)^2}\\[1em]
S(2)&\quad=\quad&\frac{a}{\left(1-r\right)^2}+\frac{2ar}{\left(1-r\right)^3}\\[1em]
S(3)&\quad=\quad&
\frac{a}{\left(1-r\right)^2}+
\frac{6ar}{\left(1-r\right)^4}\\[1em]
S(4)&\quad=\quad&
\frac{a}{1-r}+\frac{15ar}{\left(1-r\right)^2}+
\frac{50ar^2}{\left(1-r\right)^3}+
\frac{60ar^3}{\left(1-r\right)^4}+
\frac{24ar^4}{\left(1-r\right)^5}\\
\end{array}
$$

Now pause to consider a sort of generalized arithmetic sequence whose $n^{th}$ term may be written:

$$a_n=\sum_{i=0}^k \left(\!\begin{array}{c}n-1\\i\end{array}\!\right)c_i(k)$$

Sequences whose $n^{th}$ term is $n^k$ can be shown to belong
to this family, with the following values of $c_i(k)$ (for $k=0,1,2,3,4$):

\begin{array}{lll}
1,1,1,1,1,\dots,n^0&\qquad &k=0, c_0=1\\[1em]
1,2,3,4,5,\dots,n^1&\qquad &k=1, c_0=1,c_1=1\\[1em]
1,4,9,16,25,\dots,n^2&\qquad& k=2, c_0=1,c_1=3,c_2=2\\[1em]
1,8,27,64,125,\dots,n^3&\qquad& k=3, c_0=1,c_1=7,c_2=12,c_3=6\\[1em]
1,16,81,256,625,\dots,n^4&\qquad& k=4, c_0=1,c_1=15,c_2=50,c_3=60,c_4=24\\[1em]
\end{array}

Since originally posting this question, I've learned that the
values of $c_i(k)$ are called Worpitzky numbers ([A028246](http://oeis.org/A028246)).
You can generate them by multiplying the Stirling number
of the second kind $\left\{\begin{array}{c}n\\k\end{array}\right\}$ by $\left(k-1\right)!$.

I am seeing a coincidence between the coefficients in terms of $S(k)$ and corresponding values of $c_i(k)$. But I don't know how to predict the exact form of $S(k)$ given $k$.

Answer (score 0):

$S(k)$ is a polylogarithm of negative index $k$ scaled by $a$ and divided by $r$:
$$S(k)=\frac{a(-1)^{k}}{r}\sum_{j=0}^kj!\left\{\begin{array}{c}k+1\\j+1\end{array}\right\}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{(1-r)^{j+1}}$$

Comment: This saved my day!!!
Seriously, got some result containing something quite similar to these monsters, and was absolutely stuck on how to deal with it... now that I know what it is, I may be able to get it into a more convenient form, Thank you very much!